# Fastest validation query in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, optimization

What is the fastest query in PostgreSQL, which I can use as a validationQuery binding a JNDI resource?

I thought that `SELECT 1` is the simplest, but in [this](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Surviving+Connection+Closures) document it is said that in PostgreSQL we should use `select version()`. This is not obvious to me.

I've tried to compare `EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT 1` and `EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT version()` and still can't see why second one is (or should be) faster.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is obviously nonsense. `SELECT 1` is faster (if only by a tiny bit). `version()` also returns quite a few bytes of text, in my case:

```
PostgreSQL 9.1.2 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc-4.4.real (Debian 4.4.5-8) 4.4.5, 64-bit
```

So you get some additional I/O, too.
pgAdmin, for instance, uses `SELECT 1` as validation query.

Answer (score 2):

JIRA looks at the database version when connecting to figure out things like [how it should handle escaping of strings](http://openjpa.208410.n2.nabble.com/jira-Created-OPENJPA-2056-Postgres-V9-1-issue-with-LIKE-clause-and-Escape-Strings-td6858252.html), something that changed in later versions of the database.  That's the main reason I know of they use the longer, slower version check instead of a simpler SELECT.  There may be other version specific code in there too.